# Panel not working Properly in jquery mobile 1.4.1?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panel

Hello I am creating panel in multiple pages following this example .its working perfectly in jquery mobile 1.3.2

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <!-- header -->
    <div data-role="header"> <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>contents</h1>
        <a data-role="button" href="#p2">Page 2</a>
    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- page -->
<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <!-- header -->
    <div data-role="header"> <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>contents</h1>
        <a data-role="button" href="#p1">Page 1</a>
        <a data-role="button" href="#p3">Page 3</a>
    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- page -->
<div data-role="page" id="p3">
    <!-- header -->
    <div data-role="header"> <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>contents</h1>
        <a data-role="button" href="#p2">Page 2</a>
    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="right" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p></div>';

$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role=page]', function () {
    if ($(this).find('[data-role=panel]').length === 0) {
        $('[data-role=header]').before(panel);
    }
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () {
        $(this).trigger('pagecreate');
    });
});
```

When i use this example in jquery mobile 1.4.1 its not working.The panel only working initially but when i go to next page the panel not working properly? how to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions for this:

- **Solution one:**

  Use an *External* panel that can be accessed from any page, this is in case you want to have the same panel contents in all pages.

  Append panel to `$.mobile.pageContainer` **once** only on `pagebeforecreate` and then *enhance* the panel using `$(".selector").panel()`.

  ```
  var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="right" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p></div>';

  $(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panel);
    $("#mypanel").panel();
  });
  ```

  Add button to open the panel in each header (or wherever you want).

  ```
  <a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-corner-all"></a>
  ```

  > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3qVJw/)**

---

- **Solution two:**

  If you wish to do changes to panel before appending it, based on number of pages in DOM, add panel to each one with a *different* ID and a button to open that panel.

  Note that you don't need to call any kind of enhancement, because you're adding panels on `pagebeforecreate`. Hence, panels will be auto-initialized once page is *created*.

  ```
  var i = 1;

  var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel"' + i + '"" data-position="right" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p></div>';

  var panelBtn = '<a href="#mypanel"' + i + '"" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-corner-all"></a>'

  $(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
      $.mobile.pageContainer.find("[data-role=page]").each(function () {
          $(this).prepend(panel);
      });
      $.mobile.pageContainer.find("[data-role=header]").each(function () {
          $(this).append(panelBtn);
      });
      i++;
  });
  ```

  > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7bCU3/)**

**Note:** Make sure you use `.one()` not `.on()`, if you use the latter, panels will be added whenever a page is created.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of panel worked fine. But href provided in the panel doesnot work.

Comment: $("#panelbtn2").on("tap",function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("#mainPage2");

    });  Solved by this